# Defining a save path in VB

Tags: vbscript

The script creates a txt file of info from the users PC then saves it to a shared directory folder F:\InstalledSoftware\

```
If WriteFile(s, sFileName) Then
  'optional prompt for display
  If MsgBox("Finished processing.  Results saved to " & sFileName & _
            vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Do you want to view the results now?", _
            4 + 32, sTitle) = 6 Then
    WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """" & sFileName & """", 9
  End If
End If
```

> A) sFileName = "F:\InstalledSoftware\"
>   & sCompName & "_" & GetDTFileName() &
>   "_Software.txt"
>
> B) sFileName =  sCompName & "_" &
>   GetDTFileName() & "_Software.txt"

both result in a file being created e.g  “ JOHNPC_05112011_093842_Software.txt”

but B correctly creates it in the current active directory.

Two problems,  As I have as shared drive, if I email the link to the VB script, I have to use exhibit A as exhibit B uses the current active directory.
The second problem is the F: drive is mapped on some machines as a different drive letter J or K or in virtual environments a different drive. But exhibit B will always work as long as I am in the correct folder.

Is there a different way of designating the path. i.e

IP Address or DNS name that does not use a Drive letter?

> sFileName =
>   "????????????????\InstalledSoftware\"
>   & sCompName & "…………..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the UNC path of the location the drive is mapped to;

`sFileName = "\\server_name_or_ip\optional_path\InstalledSoftware\" & sCompName & ..."`

Comment: Thanks Alex sometimes we over look the simple answer